# NHibernate MySql transaction does not rollback

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

i am using nhibernate with a MySql database.

Most CRUD operations work as expected except rolling back a transaction. The following code is what i have; really straightforward, create an entity, save it, then rollback.

```
using (var tran = accountRepository.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var newUser = new User();
            newUser.Username = "testuser1002";

            accountRepository.Session.Save(newUser);

            tran.Rollback();
        }
```

The code yield expected result in my **SqlServer** configuration, however, it does not work with the **MySql** configuration. These 2 configurations are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using InnoDb storage engine and not MyIsam if you need transactions. This [article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html) has some good explanations and advises.